# How to list all binary expression trees with given leaves

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

If i have a list of leaf nodes and nonleaf nodes with specified arities, how can I effieciently enumerate the possible trees?

For example:

```
leafNodes={1,2,3,4,5} 
nonLeafNodes=<|a->2, b -> 3, c->2|>
```

Should return 311 trees:

```
a->{c->{1, 2}, b->{3, 4, 5}}, etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 11, the new function `Groupings` does precisely what you want:

```
Groupings[{1,2,3,4,5}, {a->2, b->3, c->2}]
```

[image]